# Does Cypress support pre-execution checks?

Tags: cypress

I run Cypress from the terminal using an npm script. I would like to run a series of checks before any tests in any spec are executed (e.g. to ensure env variables are set as expected).
If any check fails, I'd like to log some debug info and Cypress to mark each spec as failed.

Is something like this possible without having to have a custom script that executes before Cypress is started?

I've played around with the support file, but logging to the terminal and failing all test specs seems problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [Before Run API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-run-api)

```
on('before:run', (details) => {
  /* ... */
})
```